# Use of the Zero Vector for proving Non-emptiness?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**Why is proving **Non-emptiness** treated as synonymous with showing the $0$ vector exists (the set contains it)?**

[Edit: I believe there is some confusion around how this is taught which I'm experiencing, the [top voted answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778623/why-does-the-definition-of-a-linear-subspace-asks-for-non-emptiness) "We need to have the 0 vector in any subspace so it can not be empty." is a perfect example of what I'm trying to get at...this person wouldn't have said this, or people wouldn't have voted it, unless they'd experienced the same confusion? See more below, thank you!]

Let's take a subset $S \subseteq V = \Bbb R^2$

Let S = {**x** $\in \Bbb R^2 | 2x_1 + x_2 = 4$} i.e. the line with slope $-2$ and $y$ Intercept $4$.

Clearly this set is Non-empty (the line is a collection of points), but it is not closed under vector addition or scalar multiplication e.g:

1. $(1,2)^T + (2,0)^T = (3,2)^T \notin S$,
2. $3(1,2)^T \notin S$

But often the reason sited, for it and other sets, not being a subspace is that it doesn't contain the $0$ vector. And whether a set contains the $0$ Vector or not, is lumped into whether or not is satisfies Non-Emptiness. 5:20 in this [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGXxfLcFEw0&list=PLcjqUUQt__ZGLhwUacPm7_RKs2eJNFwco&index=25) is an example.

Why is there this focus on the $0$ Vector for satisfying non emptiness. Obviously the set described is Non-empty. So why are we even mentioning Non-emptiness, surely we should be talking about it's failure under Scalar Multiplication of Vector Addition?

1. I understand why we have the non-empty criteria, because otherwise scalar multiplication and point wise addition are vacuously true for the empty set.
2. I understand that we must have the 0 Vector to satisfy the additive identity.
3. I understand that it's often convent to satisfy showing that the ) vector exists as a way of satisfying the additive identity and no non emptiness. (As alluded to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170268/how-to-prove-a-subspace-is-non-empty))
4. I can imagine that not containing the $0$ vector will be indicative of some failure under scalar multiplication or vector addition.

But none of this gives me a satisfactory intuition for why "Proving the set is Non-empty" is synonymous with proving it contains the 0 Vector. As per my example, this set is Non-empty but does not contain the 0 vector? Unless I have a fundamental misunderstanding of non-emptiness or another concept.

Thanks!

**More examples:**

To rephrase the question, a set contains the $0$ vector seems to show us that the additive identity is satisfied, and is necessary but not sufficient for closure under scalar multiplication and point wise addition. It is sufficient for non emptiness, but so is any other object, so why do we make so much special fuss in relation to the $0$ vector.

I.e. I don't believe what's so special about the presence of the 0 vector Is that the set is non-empty we could show that with anything else. It's these other things that the $0$ vector shows us.

- Statements in textbooks like "S is non-empty, since **0** = $0$**v** $\in S$" [Martin Anthony & Michele Harvey, Linear Algebra Concepts and Methods, p.155, p.159, p.160, p.166, p.237, p.457, p459] just feel very misleading with regards to what the existence of the $0$ vectors is actually showing us?
- This [stack user](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170268/how-to-prove-a-subspace-is-non-empty) clearly had the same issue. But I didn't find the answers too satisfactory, as it feels like they're just saying it's "Convenient coincidence."
- Another example: The top voted answer on this [stack post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778623/why-does-the-definition-of-a-linear-subspace-asks-for-non-emptiness) is wrong I believe "We need to have the 0 vector in any subspace so it can be non-empty". But clearly illustrates that there is some kind of frustration/misunderstanding around how people are learning this, that I am also experiencing and trying to get help with here....
- This comment here is [another example](https://youtu.be/QGXxfLcFEw0?t=1216https://).

Comment: "Clearly" $\{\,\mathbf x\in\Bbb R^2\mid 2x_1+x_2=4\,\}$ is non.empty? Is $\{\,\mathbf x\in\Bbb R^2\mid 2x_1^2+x_2^2=-4\,\}$ also clearly non-empty? After all, it *is* a collection of points.

Comment: S not including the zero vector ist just the easiest way for proving S is not a vector space. than the other arguments are not necessary

Comment: Hey @HagenvonEitzen thank you for your reply! So I think the point you are making is that not sets represented by an equation are obviously non-empty? I'm not sure I understand, as your example Is clearly empty I would have thought. But a line like the one I suggested is clearly non-empty. Like I mentioned at the end, perhaps i'm fundamentally misunderstanding non-emptiness? I'd be grateful if you have time to expand, thanks!

Comment: Hi @trula thanks for your reply as well. So I mention in the 4 points at the end, that I understand it's a convenient way of killing two birds with one stone. But I don't understand why we refer to this with regards to non-emptiness, why don't we instead have including the 0 vector as related to proving closure under addition and multiplication. I just don't get it's intimate relationship with non-emptiness found in every text book? Thanks! I think beyond just convince or conscience it kinda needs spelling out to me.

Comment: For a vector space $V$, a subspace $W$ must be nonempty. Nonemptiness is usually demonstrated by *exhibiting* an explicit vector that is in $W$. Any vector will do. That said, however, there is only one vector from $V$ that we know will **definitely** be in any subspace: namely $\mathbf{0}$. This is the only vector of $V$ with that property, since the set $\{\mathbf{0}\}$ contains *only* the zero vector, and is a subspace. Thus, when confronted with a set that you want to show is or is not a subspace, a good vector to exhibit to show nonemptiness is the zero vector.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin this was the key I was looking for. The key fact is, that because it's the only guaranteed vector, we try to check it. I would accept this as the answer if you were to post it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your assertion

> "Proving the set is Non-empty" is synonymous with proving it contains
> the $0$ Vector

is false. A set can be nonempty and not contain the $0$ vector.

The question leading to your question seems to be about proving that some subset of a vector space is not a subspace. Often that argument will involve showing

> it does not contain $0$

or

> it is not closed under vector addition

Those conditions are not equivalent. Either will do when you want to show a subset is not a subspace. Even when both are true,   one is might be easier to prove than the other.

**Edit**  in response to comments and the edited question.

- The first bullet point claims that

> "$S$ is non-empty, since $0 = 0v ∈$"

is misleading. It's certainly correct. It's misleading only if you read it as implying that's the only way to show the set is nonempty. The OP suggests that is in fact how many people read it.

- In the first answer the second bullet point links to you find

> Well, in general if you want to prove that a set  is not empty, then
> you just have to prove that it contains an element. This element can
> be the 0 element or any other (this don't matter).

which the OP finds unsatisfactory because it says

> it feels like they're just saying it's "Convenient coincidence."

I think that is exactly what they are saying, and it is the answer to the logical part of the OP's question.

- From the third new bullet point

> Another example: The top voted answer on [this stack post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4606001/use-of-the-zero-vector-for-proving-non-emptiness/4606011?noredirect=1#comment9705943_4606011) is wrong I
> believe "We need to have the 0 vector in any subspace so it can be
> non-empty". But clearly illustrates that there is some kind of
> frustration/misunderstanding around how people are learning this, that
> I am also experiencing and trying to get help with here....

That answer is in fact correct. It very carefully addresses the distinction between proving that a potential subspace is nonempty and proving that it contains $0$.

That said, I agree that it does not address the question behind the OP's question, which seems to be "why is this so confusing to me and to other people?"

All I can suggest is that perhaps a text that focuses on proofs for people who have never seen them before might add a remark saying something like

> When proving that a subset $S$ of a vector space is a subspace one of
> the things you have to show is that it is not empty.
>
> You might think that would follow once you have proved that $S$ is
> closed under scalar multiplication, since for any $v \in S$ you have
> $0 \cdot v 0 \in S$. But that is a circular reasoning, unless you
> already know there is such a $v$. So you really do have to find
> something in $S$. How you do that depends on how $S$ has been
> described in the hypotheses. Usually (but not always) the easiest
> thing to check is that $0 \in S$.

I might consider that worth mentioning in a lecture, or perhaps once in a book. But to repeat it often would be distracting.

- I have not looked at the video in the fourth bullet point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ethan Bolker. I completely agree, that the assertion is false. That is the point of my question, why are they so often lumped together?. Often a lecturer, or textbook will say "The set does not contain the  0 vector and therefore does not satisfy non-emptiness" or we are taught that to prove the set doesn't satisfy non-emptiness, just show it doesn't contain the 0 Vector." Why are they lumped together like this, when as you say a set can be non-empty without including the 0 vector?

Comment: I doubt that you will find either of the phrases  "The set does not contain the 0 vector and therefore does not satisfy non-emptiness" in a book since it is false. or "to prove the set doesn't satisfy non-emptiness, just show it doesn't contain the 0 Vector" in a book since both are false. If you can provide a direct quote in  your question we may be able to help.

Comment: Hi @Ethan Bolker! the quote I have provided in my edit is a direct quote of the kind of thing im thinking of. I will edit it nowto include age number and author, also the video link I provided In the original question gives a similar example of how "non-emptiness" and not including zero are lumped together. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: For context I know the assertion is false, and I'm not trying to claim the are saying that. Im just trying to understand why non-emptiness is often lumped together with proving the 0 vector isn't included in the set. When it seems that any vector will do, and often showing non-emptiness doesn't seem to be the main benefit of showing the existence of the 0 vector.

Comment: Also the top voted answer on this stack post is wrong "We need to have the 0 vector in any subspace so it can be non-empty". But clearly illustrates that there is some kind of frustration/misunderstanding around this, that I am also experiencing....https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778623/why-does-the-definition-of-a-linear-subspace-asks-for-non-emptiness

Comment: Thanks again @Ethan Bolker for your careful answer on all these points. It's bothered me for a while, so I appreciate you taking the time, despite it being slightly tedious for you I imagine! The link in your answer circles back to an answer on this post I believe, my link was to a separate post, I hope that is just a misunderstanding I wasn't trying to critique anyone here. The answer in the separate post says "We need to have the 0 vector in any subspace so it can be non-empty". In this logical statement is the presence of the 0 vector, the consequent, as it is necessary for non-emptiness?

Comment: That statement is wrong. You do not need the zero vector to prove the set is nonempty. Think about the positive reals, which are nonempty and closed under addition. But once the set is nonempty (for any reason) and closed under scalar multiplication it will contain $0$.

Comment: Thanks @Ethan Bolker, that's what I thought. So with regards to My 3rd bullet point where I say 'the answer on this [other] stack post is wrong.' I'm not sure if you followed the link? I wasn't talking about your answer I was talking about another answer on a separate post, where someone literally says the statement you just agreed is wrong. I'd be super grateful if you could just take 5 seconds, to double check the link, and clarify that that is indeed wrong. Otherwise I'm slightly confused between you post and your latest comment. Thanks again, and apologies for not making that clear.

Comment: As a sentence standing alone that answer is a true statement. You are correct that it does not answer the question. There's a correct answer in the comments that points out that the problem is with the empty set, which is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: hahah I think I'm losing my mind. But you just said the statement that im referring too "We need to have the 0 vector in any subspace so it can be non-empty" which is the top voted answer in that other post with 4 upvotes, is wrong, and you cited the example of the positive reals!? Hahaha I promise the recurring nightmare will end soon! This post, the top voted answer, 4 upvotes...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778623/why-does-the-definition-of-a-linear-subspace-asks-for-non-emptiness

Answer (score 1):

While $\mathbf 0\in S$ is not *directly* on your preferred checklist for subvectorspaceness, it is still a necessary condition for a subspace (because we can show for every subspace $S$ that $\mathbf0\in S$: By nonemptyenss, there is some $v\in S$, then also $(-1)\cdot v\in S$ and $\mathbf0=v+(-1)\cdot v\in S$, or why not more directly: $\mathbf0=0\cdot v\in S$).

Hence showing that $\mathbf0\notin S$ is often the *fastest* way to show that some given $S$ fails to be a subspace. Of course you will (provided $S$ is nonempty to begin with) always also be *able* to find $v,w\in S$ with $v+w\notin S$, or $v\in S$ and $a\in\mathbf F$ with $a\cdot v\notin S$. But this may cost you a split-second more work because it may happen by chance tat your first few random picks of candidates for counterexamples happen to accidentally not be counterexamples ...

Comment: Hi @Hagen von Eitzen correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe what you are saying is that showing the set contains the 0 vector shows us that the additive identity is satisfied? And that it is necessary but not sufficient for close under addition and scalar multiplication? But that still begs the question, why is it linked in lectures and textbooks to non-emptiness, surely it should be linked to those things?

Comment: No, it is not true that if $S$ contains the zero vector then the additive identity is satisfied; and no, this answer does not make that assertion. This answer simply says that if $S$ is a subspace then $\mathbf 0 \in S$; and the contrapositive is therefore also true, if $\mathbf 0 \not\in S$ then $S$ is not a subspace.

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification hagen , really helpful, appreciate you taking the time!